# Split the string at various index position

Tags: java, regex, string, substring, split

I am trying to solve this in Java. I have a long string of information and I want to split the string based on the length of the fields given.

Example: `FirstNameLastName yy-mm-dd549Eastwolframstreet

I have a list of fields given along with its length. There are n number of fields.
example fields:

- FirstName length: 9
- LastName length: 9
- Date length: 8
- Address: 30

If the name is less than 9 characters spaces occupy the remaining positions.
i.e Lastname is length 9 but there are only 8 letters remaining one is a space.

What is the best way to extract those fields from each of its given length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    String value = "FirstNameLastName yy-mm-ddAddress                       FirstNameLastName yy-mm-ddAddress                       FirstNameLastName yy-mm-ddAddress                       ";

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("First Name : "+value.substring(i, i + 9));
        System.out.println("Last Name : "+value.substring((i + 9), i + 18));
        System.out.println("Date : "+value.substring(i + 18, i + 26));
        System.out.println("Address : "+value.substring(i + 26, i + 56));
        i = i + 55;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that each part is an exact length--and if it happens to be less, it's padded by spaces--this is a perfect situation for using [`String.substring(i,i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

For example: `str.substring(0, 9)` is the first nine characters. Now trim it, and any extra pad-spaces will be eliminated.

Comment: I have edited my question. Each field is not of same length. I need to read the fields and as well as the string to split the string.

Comment: "If the name is less than 9 characters spaces occupy the remaining positions. i.e Lastname is length 9 but there are only 8 letters remaining one is a space." Name is always 9 characters. If it's less, then it's padded with spaces. That seems to be what you're saying...

Comment: Substring is definitely one of the option. trying to see a more efficient way to loop through the fields and splitting it.

Comment: Given your specifications, I don't see how anything could be more efficient than these two functions.